# How is the source code for multidimensional array in C# generated

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array, roslyn, coreclr

For example we have a multidimensional array of doubles
`double[,] d = new double[1,2];`

`d.GetType()` returns `{Name = "Double[,]" FullName = "System.Double[,]"}`

`d[0,0]` is compiled to `call instance float64 float64[0..., 0...]::Get(int32, int32)` IL

How is the source code of type `System.Double[,]` generated?
Is it baked in CLR or Roslyn is responsible for its generation?

Comment: It's generated by the developers who wrote it and compiled it into the .Net runtime.

Comment: I was digging the coreclr repository on github, can't find the exact place for that logic

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan It is quite complex to find something low level in the coreclr unless you know where to look for it.

Comment: @xanatos that's why I need the help of .Net community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array types are handled in a special way by the CLR (both single-dimensional and multi-dimensional arrays and each in a different special way). For multi-dimensional arrays, all Roslyn does is to `call` the `Get()` method and the CLR takes care of the rest.

What exactly the CLR does is quite complicated (at least it seems that way to me), but I believe the most relevant part starts in [`Lowering::LowerArrElem`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/47489e02d035e207d89f54bf7714c33e24a04882/src/jit/lower.cpp#L3416-L3629).

The end result is that a method like this one:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
private static double Get(double[,] d)
{
    return d[0, 0];
}
```

compiles to the this x64 code (comments mine):

```
// stack pointer adjustment, not interesting
sub         rsp,28h  

// eax = 0
xor         eax,eax  

// range check first dimension against eax
sub         eax,dword ptr [rcx+18h]  
cmp         eax,dword ptr [rcx+10h]  
jae         00007FFD0A554521  

// edx = 0
xor         edx,edx  

// range check second dimension against edx
sub         edx,dword ptr [rcx+1Ch]  
cmp         edx,dword ptr [rcx+14h]  
jae         00007FFD0A554521  

// compute item offset
mov         r8d,dword ptr [rcx+14h]  
imul        r8,rax  
mov         rax,rdx  
add         rax,r8  

// load result into xmm0
movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [rcx+rax*8+20h]  

// stack pointer adjustment, not interesting
add         rsp,28h  

// return
ret
```

Comment: do you know why Roslyn uses `Get` method not some special IL instruction for multidimensional arrays ?

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan Because that's what [the .Net specification says it has to do](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf#page=192&zoom=auto,87,290) (and because there are no special IL instructions for multidimensional arrays). As for why the specification says that, I have no idea.

Comment: thank you, sad is that `double[n,m]` is slower than `double[n][m]`

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is in the [arraynative.cpp](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype/arraynative.cpp) and [arraynative.h](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype/arraynative.h).

Starting from [Array.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Array.cs):

```
public unsafe Object GetValue(params int[] indices)
```

uses

```
fixed(int* pIndices = indices)
    InternalGetReference(&elemref, indices.Length, pIndices);
```

Where `InternalGetReference()` is (same file):

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
// reference to TypedReference is banned, so have to pass result as pointer
private unsafe extern void InternalGetReference(void * elemRef, int rank, int * pIndices);
```

The `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall` are defined in [ecalllist.h](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/ecalllist.h) (remember this file... It contains all the `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall`, so it is quite useful) (if you don't remember the name of the file, you can simply search for `InternalGetReference` in the github... there aren't many files containing that word):

```
FCFuncElement("InternalGetReference", ArrayNative::GetReference)
```

So you have to look for `ArrayNative`, that is in the two files I linked.

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan If you look around line 1342 of arraynative.cpp I see a quite concrete implementation of `InternalGetReference` that does everything.

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan And even the `ArrayNative::CreateInstance` seems to be quite concrete... It is full of magical calls to the type system... But it is quite logical... We are digging very low level here. It is code I wouldn't touch with a 10 feet pole

Comment: The initial problem was difference between get call in multidimensional and jagged arrays

Comment: `Array.GetValue(int[])` is not the same as `double[,].Get(int, int)`.

Comment: @svick Ah yes... you are right... It is even worse then... It is probably defined somewhere in [array.cpp](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/array.cpp) There seems to be some code generator for the `Get`, `Set` and `Address` "special" functions.